# Ping a openvpn client connected to a docker container from the host of the container

Tags: openvpn, docker

I have a docker container running openvpn. I have many clients connected.
The host container is 10.3.114.143.
The docker container is 192.168.255.1.
One of the clients is 192.168.255.9.

When i ping 192.168.255.9 from inside docker container it works as expected.
When i ping 192.168.255.1 from client it pings the docker container.

What I wanted to do is ping the client (connected through openvpn to the docker container) from the host of the docker container. Is this possible?

I added to the docker configuration:

> cap_add:
>     - NET_ADMIN

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Does your host have network connectivity with the docker container via some specific network?

Comment: That's really the question isn't it... I can do whatever I want between the container and the host, I can even make them share the same network. But the point here is to be able to do what I want with the maximum separation possible

Comment: You may need special iptable rules. Were you able to solve this?